# Python gTTS not accepting strings within variables

Tags: python

I am writing a python script to scan a photo which contains text with google vision OCR, then use Google gTTS to speak the text. Here is the code:

```
#BookrBasic

from os import system
from time import sleep
from pygame import mixer
from gtts import gTTS
import subprocess


def tts(speech):
tts = gTTS(text=speech, lang='en')
tts.save("/tmp/text.mp3")
subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', '-q', '/tmp/text.mp3']).wait()

def ocr(file):
out = system('python3 ~/bookrbasic/ocr.py <KEY GOES HERE> ' + file)
return out

text = ocr("~/bookrbasic/photos/canada4.jpg")
tts(text)
```

This is the error I recieve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BookrBasic.py", line 20, in <module>
    tts(text)
  File "BookrBasic.py", line 11, in tts
    tts = gTTS(text=speech, lang='en')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 72, in     __init__
    raise Exception('No text to speak')
Exception: No text to speak
```

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I managed to fix it by writing to a file in tmp.

Here is the new code, in case anyone is having a similar issue:

```
#BookrBasic

import os 
from os import system
from time import sleep
from pygame import mixer
from gtts import gTTS
import subprocess


def tts(speech):
    tts = gTTS(text=speech, lang='en-uk')
    os.mkfifio('/tmp/fifo')
    tts.save("/tmp/text.mp3")
    subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', '-q', '/tmp/text.mp3']).wait()


def ocr(file):
    system('python3 ~/bookrbasic/ocr.py <KEY GOES HERE> ' + file + ' > /tmp/text.txt')
    with open ("/tmp/text.txt", "r") as myfile:
        out=myfile.read()
    return out

text = ocr("~/bookrbasic/photos/canada4.jpg")
tts(text)
```